# How to use HtmlUnit to run Html containing Canvas in headless mode?

Tags: javascript, canvas, htmlunit, headless-browser

I am using htmlunit 2.35.0 version to run the html in headless mode. It is working fine with html containing SVG. Now, I am using a custom JavaScript framework called geotoolkit which renders canvas images. I am facing issue when I try to run the html with canvas in headless mode using htmlunit. Please find the below code and error logs. Can anyone please let me know how to fix the issue ?

> code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

String path = Paths.get("Input/Editor").toAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"canvas.html";
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
File file = new File(path);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(file.toURI().toURL().toString());         
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);                       
System.out.println(page.asXml());
webClient.close();
```

> error logs

```
Feb 24, 2020 11:22:29 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.canvas.CanvasRenderingContext2D createImageData
    INFO: CanvasRenderingContext2D.createImageData() not yet implemented
    Feb 24, 2020 11:22:29 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener scriptException
    SEVERE: Error during JavaScript execution
    ======= EXCEPTION START ========
    EcmaError: lineNumber=[1426] column=[0] lineSource=[null] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[file:/D:/Playground/HeadlessTest/Input/BHAEditor/geotoolkit/geotoolkit.adv.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot read property "width" from undefined (file:/D:/Playground/HeadlessTest/Input/BHAEditor/geotoolkit/geotoolkit.adv.js#1426)]
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "width" from undefined (file:/D:/Playground/HeadlessTest/Input/BHAEditor/geotoolkit/geotoolkit.adv.js#1426)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:885)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:617)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:534)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:336)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:814)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:786)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2534)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2527)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:342)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeAtTargetListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:379)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.executeEventLocally(EventTarget.java:100)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeEvent(HtmlScript.java:414)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:380)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:247)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:936)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$200(JavaScriptEngine.java:104)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:880)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:617)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:534)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:336)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:814)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:786)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2534)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2527)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:342)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeAtTargetListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:379)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.executeEventLocally(EventTarget.java:100)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeEvent(HtmlScript.java:414)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:380)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:247)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:936)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$200(JavaScriptEngine.java:104)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:880)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:617)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:534)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:336)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:814)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:786)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2534)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2527)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:342)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeAtTargetListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:379)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.executeEventLocally(EventTarget.java:100)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeEvent(HtmlScript.java:414)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:380)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:247)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:936)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$200(JavaScriptEngine.java:104)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:880)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:617)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:534)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:336)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:814)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:786)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2534)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2527)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:342)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeAtTargetListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:379)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.executeEventLocally(EventTarget.java:100)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeEvent(HtmlScript.java:414)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:380)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:247)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:936)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$200(JavaScriptEngine.java:104)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:880)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:617)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:534)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:336)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:814)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:786)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2534)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2527)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the root of your problem is the not yet available implementation of CanvasRenderingContext2D.createImageData().

Please open an issue at github and i will try to fix this.

Of course any pull requests are welcome also.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. I have created the issue on github. Here is the link to it https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/140

Comment: Thanks, have seen it already - have started already to work on this. Will require some days.